# why QWebFrame is not handled in the eventFilter Function?

Tags: qt4

I want to get the Mouse Position when clicked on a QWebFrame. I am using Event Filter function  and that works fine with QWebView but it does not work either QWebFrame nor QWebPage.

Can any one please tell me how to make it work???
thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to filter events in QWebPage/QWebFrame exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

As `QWebFrame` and `QWebPage` are not widgets, they don't officially receive mouse events.

And if you look at `QWebView` event functions, you'll see that the mouse events are sent to `QWebPage` with a direct call to `QWebPage::event`, they would need to be sent with `QCoreApplication::postEvent` or `sendEvent` to pass through the `eventfilter`.

If you want to filter these events, you'll have to derive `QWebPage` to redefine its `event` function. And no event is ever forwarded to `QWebFrame`.